# How to do local debug step by step in worker role of azure application?

Tags: debugging, azure, worker, role

When I was trying to do local debug, unable to trace line by line since I have multiple projects and references are not been called from one to another.
Please provide help at the earliest.

Thanks,
Bujji Babu P.

Comment: You really don't give much information at all other than "please help be debug in azure". Hard to assist in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the more details? I dont think multiple project would effect debugging step by step,make sure focus on the line and F11 is available.